# Create a PowerShell script to load the data from the .CSV flat file to a table in test environment

Tags: sql-server, powershell, csv

I have a .CSV flat file I want to create a PowerShell script to load that flat file into the SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: What approaches have you already tried to solve this problem? (Please include them in your answer).

Comment: I have never tried anything because i don't know how to do this.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for powershell and SQL server management studio. It is possible that SQL server management studio has instructions for how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, for your help. I got solution from Microsoft documentation for SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell CSV to SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38952485/powershell-csv-to-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$query = @'

BULK INSERT dbname.dbo.anything FROM ‘Csvpath’

WITH (FIRSTROW = firstrow, FIELDTERMINATOR = ‘fieldterminator’, ROWTERMINATOR = ‘\rowterminator’)

'@

Invoke-SqlCmd2 -ServerInstance '$env:computername\sql1' -Database databasename -Query $query
```

Comment: Please use straight quotes instead of the curly ones in code